# Numpy Partition does not work as expected

Tags: python, numpy

From what I understand, the array given should have `20` before `30` in this example. Why is `20` sorted as a number larger than `30`?

Reasoning: `np.partition` should split on the value `30` and put all values less than `30` on the left of it, and all values larger than `30` to the right. `20` is less than `30` but to `30`s right.

```
nums = np.array([70, 50, 20, 30, -11, 60, 50, 40])
print(nums[3])
print(np.partition(nums, 3))
>>> 30
>>> array([-11,  30,  20,  40,  50,  60,  50,  70])
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `partition` is a little tricky; you also need to check the examples.  When you specify the position at which to partition, you are giving the *sorted* position.  Your call says "give me a partition -- an unfinished sort -- of `nums`.  Make sure that the element 3 is in the right spot."

The third element of the *sorted* array is 40, not 30.  You are surprised (which I understand), but the documentation is correct.  This is used for a lot of recursive routines that partition arrays at strategic points, such as the merge sort.  You want to pick a strategic *position*, rather than guessing at a pivot value.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks! Looks like I need to work on my reading comprehension.

Comment: Don't worry about your comprehension yet -- the documentation is not clear, until the examples disambiguate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Index **3** is the **4th** element, which in the final sorted array is **40**. Notice that all the elements left of 40 are smaller than it and all those to the right are larger.

From the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html):

> kth: Element index to partition by. The k-th
> value of the element will be in its final sorted position and all
> smaller elements will be moved before it and all equal or greater
> elements behind it.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks! Looks like I need to work on my reading comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
def partition(pred, iterable):
    trues = []
    falses = []
    for item in iterable:
        if pred(item):
            trues.append(item)
        else:
            falses.append(item)
    return trues, falses
```

Usage

```
trues, falses = partition(lambda x: x > 10, [1,4,12,7,42])
```

Output:

```
trues
[12, 42]
falses
[1, 4, 7]
```

or this code:

```
import numpy as geek
out_arr = geek.partition(nums, (0, 3))
print ("Output partitioned array : ", out_arr)
```

Comment: Thanks! Though I dont see why my example happened still. Should 20 be sorted to the left of 30?